# Writing to temp array from text file

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, console-application

I asked this before but most people don't understand my question.

I have two text files. `Gamenam.txt` which is the text file I'm reading from, and gam`enam_2.txt`.

In the `gamenam.txt` I have strings like this:

```
01456
02456
05215
05111
01421
03117
05771
01542
04331
05231
```

I have written a code `to count number of times substring "05" appears in text file before substring "01"`.

My output which is written to `gamenam_1.txt` is:

```
01456
02456
05215
05111
2
01421
03117
05771
1
01542
04331
05231
1
```

This was the code I wrote to achieve

```
string line;
int counter = 0;
Boolean isFirstLine = true;
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Files\\gamenam.txt");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Files\\gamenam_1.txt");

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "01")
        {
            if (!isFirstLine)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString());
                counter = 0;
            }
        }

        if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "05")
        {
            counter++;
        }

        sw.WriteLine(line);

        if (sr.Peek() < 0)
        {
            sw.Write(counter.ToString());
        }

        isFirstLine = false;
    }

    sr.Close();
    sw.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception finally block.");
}
```

That code is working perfectly.

Now I have to write a code ***to print the count of substring "05" before writing lines***.

My output should look something like this:

```
2
01456
02456
05215
05111
1
01421
03117
05771
1
01542
04331
05231
```

Apparently I should write the lines first to temporary string array, the count and then write count and then after write lines from my temporary array.

I'm new to development so I'm stuck trying to figure out how I'd achieve this.

Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Print on console window?

Comment: Side note - if you got answer to your previous question, then make sure you accepted answer which was most useful to you

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I'm very greatful. For everyone's input as I've stated

Comment: shouldnt your output look like                                       4 01456 02456 05215 05111 1 01421 03117 05771 1 01542 04331 05231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string line;
int counter = 0;
Boolean isFirstLine = true;
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Files\\gamenam.txt");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Files\\gamenam_1.txt");

    var lines = new List<string>(); //Here goes the temp lines
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "01")
        {
            if (!isFirstLine)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString()); //write the number before the lines
                foreach(var l in lines)
                    sw.WriteLine(l);  //actually write the lines
                counter = 0;
                lines.Clear(); //clear the list for next round
            }
        }

        if (line.Substring(0, 2) == "05")
        {
            counter++;
        }

        lines.add(line); //instead of writing, just adds the line to the temp list

        if (sr.Peek() < 0)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(counter.ToString()); //writes everything left
            foreach(var l in lines)
                sw.WriteLine(l);
        }

        isFirstLine = false;
    }

    sr.Close();
    sw.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception finally block.");
}
```

Comment: I'm kind of new with working with text files, I get a error on both lines where you specified foreach(var 1 in lines)

Comment: I tried running you code but my output shows all the lines line by line, and shows, what I think is the total of all lines with substring "05". What my code intends to do is read line by line and store the lines somewhere, might be a list or even a array temporarily and print the number of times a substring "05" occurs before loop gets to substring "01" and then write the count afterwards write down all lines in the temporary object.

Comment: It's var "l" the letter, not "1" the number

Comment: so, is it possible to possible to place the lines into list / table whilst my program is reading lines to get the count of 05, but when getting to 01, write/print count and then write the line stored in the temp object, and so on, till I have no more lines to read. Because I basically want the count first to print and then the lines below.

Comment: And what's the problem with the code provided? I mean, that's what is supposed to be doing.